# How to put a text coming after a div inside the div?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have the following circle and header.

I want the h4 to be centered inside the animating-circle div. I cannot put inside because I will rotate the circle, and I do not want the text to rotate.

I have the following CSS. Currently, all circles are stacked into each other. I want them to have their own spacing. Thanks!

```css
.animating-circle {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: #f1c40f;
  border-right-color: skyblue;
  border-bottom-color: violet;
  border-left-color: lightgray;
}

.animating-circle+h4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class='animating-circle'></div>
<h4>Title is here</h4>
```

Comment: I do not see circle on running your code please share reproduceable example

Comment: It was using `className` instead of `class`, I've edited to make the snippet work

Comment: Are you just looking to center the text? You say all circles are stacked but I only see one circle